# Localize String passed to a view

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm trying to localize some text passed to a view, I have the following:

```
NavigationLink(destination: ManageConnectionsView(user: user).navigationBarTitle("", displayMode: .inline)) {
    SettingsRowsView(systemName: "greetingcard", image: "", title: "Connections")
}
```

I want to localize `"Connections"`

I tried:

```
NavigationLink(destination: ManageConnectionsView(user: user).navigationBarTitle("", displayMode: .inline)) {
    SettingsRowsView(systemName: "greetingcard", image: "", title: LocalizedStringKey("Connections"))
}
```

but says:
`Cannot convert value of type 'LocalizedStringKey' to expected argument type 'String'`

What's the correct way of doing this without creating an extra variable?

Edit:

I found this looking around:
`String.localizedStringWithFormat(NSLocalizedString("Connections", comment: ""))`

Is this the latest workaround or is there a simpler more SwiftUI version?

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/65623431/12299030?

Comment: No. The guy’s answer is what I said on my question that I tried. I already went over that post :/ thanks @Asperi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `SettingsRowsView` to take a `LocalizedStringKey` for the `title` instead of taking a `String`.