# Multi-Line Localizable String In SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, localizable.strings

I need a key/value pair in my Swift Localizable file to by multi line but nothing seems to be working. This is what I've tried:

```
"someKey" = "Line 1 \n Line 2";

Text(someKey)
    .lineLimit(2)
```

The result is one line like this: `Line 1...`

Comment: Can't reproduce can you supply a github demo ?

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/65623431/12299030?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the container of the Text view is too narrow. Please provide more info.
Try:
`.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)`